# Conditional PDF & Expected Value for a Joint Distribution - can someone check my work?

Tags: calculus, probability, multivariable-calculus

joint pdf for random variables x,y is:
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = c*e^{-x}*e^{-y}\space\space\space 0\leq x \leq 1 \space\space\space y \geq x$$
Find  $E[X|Y]$  and $E[Y|X]$
To find E[X|Y] and E[Y|X], conditional pdf is needed 
$$f_{x|y}(x) = \frac{f_{x,y}(x,y)}{f_y(y)}$$
$$f_X(x) = ce^{-2x}\space\space\space 0\leq x \leq 1$$
$$f_Y(y) = \left\{ \begin{aligned} ce^{-y}(1-e^{-y}) &,\quad 0 \le y \le 1 \\ ce^{-y}(1-e^{-1}) &,\quad y > 1 \end{aligned}\right.$$

$$f_{x|y}(x) = \left\{ \begin{aligned} \frac{ce^{-x}e^{-y}}{ce^{-y}(1-e^{-y})} &,\quad 0 \le y \le 1 \\ \frac{ce^{-x}e^{-y}}{ce^{-y}(1-e^{-1})} &,\quad y > 1 \end{aligned}\right.$$
$$f_{x|y}(x) = \left\{ \begin{aligned} \frac{e^{-x}}{(1-e^{-y})} &,\quad 0 \le y \le 1 \\ \frac{e^{-x}}{(1-e^{-1})} &,\quad y > 1 \end{aligned}\right.$$

$$f_{y|x}(y) = \frac{e^{-y}}{e^{-x}} ,\quad 0 \le x \le 1 $$

Are my conditional PDFs correct? What is the next step in finding E[X|Y] and E[Y|X]?

Answer (score 1):

Your conditional pdfs are right.  Next $E(X/Y) = \int_{0}^{1} x f_{x/y}(x)dx, 0\lt y\lt 1$

$E(X/Y) =  \int_{0}^{1} x f_{x/y}(x)dx, y>1$

and similarly $E(Y/X) =  \int_{0}^{\infty}y f_{y/x}(y)dy $

Comment: Why are integration bounds for $E[X|Y]$ from 0 to 1?

Comment: Suppose you have $y\lt 2$ and $E(X/Y<2) = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2} xf_{x/y}(x)dx$  I think so, you take the range of XY and the interesection of that with Y<2.

Comment: $$f_{x|y}(x) = \left\{ \begin{aligned} \frac{e^{-x}}{(1-e^{-y})} &,\quad 0 \le y \le 1 \\ \frac{e^{-x}}{(1-e^{-1})} &,\quad y > 1 \end{aligned}\right.$$
So I would ignore the second term (y>1) completely and solely integrate from 0 to 1 the first term?
How would integrating from 1 to infinity work for $f_{y|x}$, because $f_{y|x}$ is bounded by $0 \leq x \leq 1$

Comment: No, I made a mistake in the previous comment.  It should be  $E(X/Y<2) = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{xe^{-x}}{(1-e^{-y})}dydx + \int_{0}^{1} \int_{1}^{2} \frac{xe^{-x}}{(1-e^{-1})}dydx $.

Comment: What if I am looking for E[X|Y] and not E[X|Y<2]?

Comment: You will have to run it through the whole of x and y under xf(x/y).

Comment: So for X|Y, am I looking at integration bounds from 0 to 1 and 1 to infinity?
And for Y|X am I looking at integration bounds from 0 to 1?